# What is c data type for python dictionary/object/json in Cython?

Tags: python, json, postgresql, cython

I have a .pyx file. To implement the Cython, I must define the variable with cdef. So I replace the python version definition to cython one.

From this (.py file):

```
sql = """ SELECT * FROM vendors; """
conn = None
response = None
```

To this (.pyx file):

```
cdef char[120] sql = """ SELECT * FROM vendors; """
cdef ??????? conn = None
cdef ??????? response = None
```

I'm new in Cython. I don't know what are the c datatype for conn and response variables. Since the value of conn & response would be as we can see below.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(**params) 
response = json.dumps(items)
```

I tried the char[], struct, enum, but they caused me errors. What are the proper datatypes for conn and response? Could you give the reference about cython datatypes?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are Python functions returning Python objects. There is unlikely to be any advantage to specifying a type for either of them. It's also pretty likely that defining the type for `sql` is not helping (it'll be converted to a Python string anyway when it's passed to a Python function). You can either leave the Python code as is (it's still valid Cython code) or specify `cdef object` as the type.

If you insist of specifying a type then response is a Python string (`cdef str response`). This may allow some tiny optimizations is Cython, but is unlikely to give much.

`conn` is a [Psycopg2 connection object](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/psycopg/connection.h#L84) which is actually defined in C. You could attempt to wrap that as [an external extension type](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#external-extension-types) to gain direct access to its attributes. This is unlikely to be a useful thing to do - it won't give you any advantage unless you have specific attributes that you want to probe through Cython.

---

This is not the sort of code that benefits from Cython - it's manipulating Python objects through Python interfaces rather than numeric data - and therefore you should not be worrying about adding types.